# Enabling Gamepad Rumble/Vibration function

Tags: logitech, gamepad

I use a Logitech Cordless Rumblepad 2 longer with my dell xps l502x. But now (thanks to playing Super Meat Boy) I want to have the vibration/rumble working.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hopefully someone can prove me wrong, but AFAIK rumble generally is not available under Linux. I've actually borrowed this gamepad from a friend (while trying to find the best one for me, mostly about Linux support), and I could not get vibrations to work in neither Shank nor SMB. Neither could I with a DS3 gamepad.

Comment: Linux supports rumble perfectly fine, you can use `fftest` to check. However SDL1.2 does not support and there are only very few games that use it (e.g. WordWarVi is one of them). No idea if Shank or SMB support it on Linux.

Comment: `fftest` worked for me, with 3 different gamepad models. YMMV